# How to find video frame rate and resolution

Tags: compression

I was watching a video produced by local movie maker, on 13" MacBook and it has lines! not sure why. I was thinking maybe the movie has rendered badly. How do I find out what's the resolution and frame rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines may come from the fact that you have exported the video with interlacing. You should generally avoid interlacing for any digital end-user medium.

To find out about certain technical aspects of a video, the program [MediaInfo](http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download) is a very handy tool that can tell you a lot about the specs of your video, including basics like video resolution and framerate. Though it's very unlikely that the root of your issue is the framerate or resolution. Medianinfo can also tell you if a video is using interlacing which is more likely the cause.

Comment: Thanks, it says 720*576. Is it low res?

Comment: That sounds like it is 576i pal resolution which is an old SD format and most likely interlaced.  If the source video is that quality, you won't be able to increase the quality any, but you can have it output de-interlaced video (ie, progressive) which should play back better in video players that don't have good quality de-interlacing built in.